# cherrypy: how to access file system from cherrypy?

Tags: cherrypy

I am working on a cherrpy web service to work with my web app. In this service it needs to be able to access the file system. For example, I want to be able to list all files under a certain directory. I am using os.walk('/public/') but don't seem to get it to work, even though the same code works outside of cherrpy.

Is there a way to make it work so I can use cherrypy to manage files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What user is the webapp running as, and does it have access to read the folder?

According to the documentation `os.walk()` will ignore errors from the underlying calls to `os.listdirs()`

http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/os-file-dir.html

You could try setting the onerror argument like

```
def print_error(error):
    print error

os.walk('/public/', print_error)
```

which might give you a hint as to what's going on.

Also, you could try going directly to `os.listdirs()` and see if you get any errors from it.

Comment: This technique solved my problem. It's a bug in my code. Thanks!